# Error 'Could not load file or assembly' while upgrading software using MSI

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have two versions of my software 3.0 and 4.0 which were built using MSI installer. Where the installer 3.0 contains NewtonSoft.Json 11.0 and the installer 4.0 contains NewtonSoft.Json 10.0. When upgrading my software from 3.0 to 4.0, I'm getting the following error. How do I resolve this?

> 'Error 1001.
> Could not load file or assembly 'NewtonSoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToke=30ad4fe6b62a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, during update of your software, NewtonSoft.Json has to be *downgraded*. I am assuming you do a major upgrade (i.e. uninstall old version, install new version).

In your InstallExecute sequence, you can schedule RemoveExistingProducts either before InstallInitialize (i.e. first uninstall old version, the install new version) or after InstallFinalize (i.e. first install new version, then uninstall old version).

The latter is more efficient but will not work in your scenario because it will not overwrite NewtonSoft.Json 11.0 with NewtonSoft.Json 10.0.

The solution therefore is to move RemoveExistingProducts to before InstallInitialize.